# cannot locate source of view_sentence_range() function in ipynb

Tags: python, function, import, jupyter

This ipynb has `view_sentence_range()` but there is no definition in the cells above nor in the `helper.py` that is imported so I have no idea where it is coming from.  Only text data is imported in cells above it is called.

I have Googled to see whether it is a Python library function, and checked `helper.py` and the text file just in case it is some sort of trick above my novice paygrade.

```
import helper

data_dir = './data/simpsons/moes_tavern_lines.txt' 
text = helper.load_data(data_dir)
# Ignore notice, since we don't use it for analysing the data
text = text[81:] #skip the notice, text is a list of words?
print(text[120:150])

view_sentence_range = (0, 10)
```

This is `helper.py`

```
import os
import pickle


def load_data(path):
    """
    Load Dataset from File
    """
    input_file = os.path.join(path)
    with open(input_file, "r") as f:
        data = f.read()

    return data


def preprocess_and_save_data(dataset_path, token_lookup, create_lookup_tables):
    """
    Preprocess Text Data
    """
    text = load_data(dataset_path)

    # Ignore notice, since we don't use it for analysing the data
    text = text[81:]

    token_dict = token_lookup()
    for key, token in token_dict.items():
        text = text.replace(key, ' {} '.format(token))

    text = text.lower()
    text = text.split()

    vocab_to_int, int_to_vocab = create_lookup_tables(text)
    int_text = [vocab_to_int[word] for word in text]
    pickle.dump((int_text, vocab_to_int, int_to_vocab, token_dict), open('preprocess.p', 'wb'))


def load_preprocess():
    """
    Load the Preprocessed Training data and return them in batches of <batch_size> or less
    """
    return pickle.load(open('preprocess.p', mode='rb'))


def save_params(params):
    """
    Save parameters to file
    """
    pickle.dump(params, open('params.p', 'wb'))


def load_params():
    """
    Load parameters from file
    """
    return pickle.load(open('params.p', mode='rb'))
```

I want to find out where this function is coming from.  BTW, this is the Udacity DL project for Simpsons script generation.  A sample project is here:  [project on github](https://github.com/RomelTorres/DLND-tv-script-generation)

Edit:

In fact, it was a tuple being defined and used later to `print`

```
print('The sentences {} to {}:'.format(*view_sentence_range))
print('\n'.join(text.split('\n')[view_sentence_range[0]:view_sentence_range[1]]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hockeymonkey33 From your code, it looks like `view_sentence_range` is used to define a tuple and is not a function.

> view_sentence_range = (0, 10)